# Оптимизация ML.Net builder

Tags: c#

Пробую работать с `ML.Net builder (price prediction)`, работает корректно, модель создана.
В основном коде описываю параметры для предикта, получаю значение, записываю в массив. Проблема в том, что работает очень долго, при записи данных действий в цикл с 2000 оборотами справляется за минут 5. Нужно обработать 45000 значений, а занимает много времени. Хотел бы узнать, возможно ли как-то оптимизировать?

Код цикла:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < dataClass.countOfElements; i++)
{
    ModelInput input = new ModelInput()
    {
        Alg1 = (float)logicClass.ValuesLog1[i],
        Alg2 = (float)logicClass.ValuesLog2[i],
        Alg3 = (float)logicClass.ValuesLog3[i],
        Alg5 = (float)logicClass.ValuesLog5[i]
    };
    var prediction = ConsumeModel.Predict(input);
    ValuesLog4[i] = prediction.Score;
}
```

Comment: Я совершенно ничего не знаю про ML.net, но начните с цикла `Parallel.For`.

Comment: Потом, у вас для каждого значения преобразование во `float`, зачем? Почему бы изначально не хранить значения в нужном формате?

Comment: Модель ML.Net builder почему-то требует именно float при создании модели.